# Nest (ElasticSearch) Update using script from sandbox

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Using NEST is there a way to invoke a script from the sandbox. In the Update Descriptor, there is ability to set the "Script", however there does not seem to be a way to instead set the script_id, which is needed. My instance of ES does not enable dynamic scripts, and I have to use the scrips from the sandbox.

The raw version of what I need to do would be something like:

`POST \MyIndex\MyType\1\_update
{
    "script_id" : "sandboxScript",
    "lang" : "groovy",
    "params" : {"Param1":"value1"}
}`

However there does not seem to be a way to set the Script Id in the UpdateDescriptor. How can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding ES documentation script_id parameter was introduced in 1.4.0 version.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/docs-update.html
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/docs-update.html

This feature is already available in the current develop branch of NEST, so you can use it or wait for version 1.4.0.

Cheers,
Robert.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I see it is now available with the 1.4  version of NEST, released a couple of days ago.

Comment: While NEST 1.4 managed seemed to support the "ScriptId", it looks like the method does not actually exists. Using it gave an error stating:
 Method not found: 'Nest.UpdateDescriptor`2<!0,!1> Nest.UpdateDescriptor`2.ScriptId(System.String)'.